# Error loading view in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to load my create view,

```
public function create()
    {
        //
        return View('my.create');
    }
```

but I'm having this error,

FatalErrorException in 85b8c1799c6cd6f2475229a36bc0e59a39b0e295.php line 23: Class 'HTML' not found

---

create.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Look! I'm CRUDding</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ URL::to('nerds') }}">Nerd Alert</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="{{ URL::to('nerds') }}">View All Nerds</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ URL::to('nerds/create') }}">Create a Nerd</a>
    </ul>
</nav>

<h1>Create a Nerd</h1>

<!-- if there are creation errors, they will show here -->
{{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'nerds')) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
        {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
        {{ Form::email('email', Input::old('email'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('nerd_level', 'Nerd Level') }}
        {{ Form::select('nerd_level', array('0' => 'Select a Level', '1' => 'Sees Sunlight', '2' => 'Foosball Fanatic', '3' => 'Basement Dweller'), Input::old('nerd_level'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    {{ Form::submit('Create the Nerd!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the above view is located in its iwn directory called my. I'm using Laravel 5.2 in WAMP server.

Comment: Post your view code, please.

Comment: You have to use an Composer.json to install HTML, HTML isn't installed by default in laravel

Comment: Is this part of your controller? Laravel has an MVC. You need to setup a controller, check your routes and then finally create and load a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're using the "classic" (has been there for long) `HTML` façade in your view.

Well, it's no longer there in Laravel > 5.1 (IIRC). If you want the same functionalities, you can refer to the LaravelCollective package you can find here:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

You can install it easily with Composer, as any other package. The same applies for the `Form` class, mind it.

Comment: what is the replacement for forms and html in Laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your class named 'HTML'.

You should create this class in your Controllers folder.

Example:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
}
```

Comment: It could be OP's using the once present HTML façade, which is not in a default install any more. While the answer is right per se, I guess it won't be suitable for OP

Answer (score 1):

1. Add these lines to your `composer.json` file:

   ```
   "require": {
       "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
   }
   ```

   and `run php composer update` (or `php.exe` on Windows)

   OR simply run from terminal:

   ```
   php.exe composer require laravelcollective/html
   ```
2. Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

   ```
   'providers' => [
       // ...
       Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
       // ...
   ],
   ```
3. Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

   ```
   'aliases' => [
       // ...
       'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
       'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
       // ...
   ],
   ```
4. Consider reading a [Documentation](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html).