# What is the replacement or how does Laravel 5.2 handle HTML and Forms?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Forms and HTML https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html does not exist in Laravel 5.2.  What is the replacement or how does Laravel 5.2 handle HTML and Forms? I checked the documentation and it appears non existent.

Comment: A quick google search would have told you the package is now optional (included via composer) and not part of the core. Check out [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html).  Also, the `illuminate/html` package has been labelled [abandoned by the author](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error loading view in Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363590/error-loading-view-in-laravel-5)

Comment: From a web framework I expect it 'knows' about Forms and provide an implementation of form generation, data validation, error handling etc. all combined in a standardized flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them back if you wish

In Composer

```
 require": {
    "illuminate/html"   : "~5.0",
```

and in you app providors

```
 'providers' => [
    ...
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
],

'aliases' => [
    ...
    'HTML'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
    'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
],
```

the more common practice since 5 is to create the forms using standard html and handle them using requests

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#retrieving-input

Answer (score 1):

Illuminate HTML is eliminated from Laravel 5 and above. But you can use Laravel Collective.

Add these lines to your `composer.json` file:

```
    "require": {
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
    }
```

Run `composer update`

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
    'providers' => [
        // ...
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        // ...
    ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
    'aliases' => [
        // ...
        'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
        // ...
    ],
```

For more reading [Documentation](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html).

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.2 users:

Install by running composer require "styde/html=~1.1" or adding "styde/html": "~1.1" to your composer.json file and then running composer update.

Laravel 5.1 users:

Install by running composer require "styde/html=~1.0" or adding "styde/html": "~1.0" to your composer.json file and then running composer update.

Next, add the new provider to the providers array in config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Styde\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
],
```

Add the following middleware to the $middleware array in app/Http/Kernel.php BEFORE the EncryptCookies middleware:

```
protected $middleware = [
    //...
    \Styde\Html\Alert\Middleware::class,
    //...
];
```

This middleware is needed to make the alert messages persistent between sessions, after each request is completed.

Please notice that the following global aliases will be automatically available (you don't need to add them):

```
Alert => Styde\Html\Facades\Alert
Field => Styde\Html\Facades\Field
Menu  => Styde\Html\Facades\Menu
Form  => Collective\Html\FormFacade
Html  => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade
If you plan to use the Access Handler as a standalone class, you will need to add the following alias:

'aliases' => [
    // ...
    'Access' => Styde\Html\Facades\Access::class,
    // ...
],
```

Optionally, you may also run `$php artisan vendor:publish --provider='Styde\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'` to publish the configuration file in config/html.php and review its options and values.

It extends Laravel Collective and comes with some framework pre built themes.